# ZK Spreadsheet with combobox

Tags: combobox, spreadsheet, zk

how can i get combobox in a ZK spreadsheet cell as shown in the link below?

[ZK spreadsheet](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spreadsheet%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spreadsheet/Configure%20and%20Control%20ZK%20Spreadsheet/Data%20Validation)

Comment: Are you using ZK EE Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
<div height="100%" width="100%" apply="org.zkoss.zssessentials.config.SheetDimensionComposer">
<combobox id="sheets">
</combobox>
<spreadsheet id="spreadsheet" src="/WEB-INF/excel/config/demo_sample.xls"
maxrows="200"
maxcolumns="40"
width="100%"
height="450px"></spreadsheet>
</div>
</zk>
```

Answer (score 0):

The combobox is a ZK Spreadsheet data validation drop down(when excel  cell validation type is a list), it is not a embedded zk combobox. I think ZK Spreadsheet doesn't support to embedded a outside zk component into it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ZK Spreadsheet but I think this could be the same behavior that in a classic listbox.

In a listbox you have to use a listbox in mold "select" instead a combobox, like this bellow.

```
<listbox id="listOfItems" model="@bind(vm.listOfItems) @template('anItem')" selectedItem="@bind(vm.selectedItem)">
  <listhead>
    <listheader label="Item-Label" hflex="1" />
    <listheader label="Thing-Label" hflex="1" />
  </listhead>
  <template name="anItem" var="i">
    <listitem>
      <listcell>
        <textbox value="@bind(i.code)" hflex="1" />
      </listcell>
      <listcell>
        <listbox mold="select" model="@bind(vm.listOfThings) @template('aThing')" selectedItem="@bind(i.selectedThing)" hflex="1">
          <template name="aThing"var="t">
            <listitem label="@load(t.label)" />
          </template>
        </listbox>
      </listcell>
    </listitem>
  </template>
</listbox>
```